# Print stapling guide marks within bindingoffset

Tags: geometry

I want to print guidelines for stapling (actually, string holes) at the left edge of the right hand page.  I've tried to use "textpos" package, but this gives marks at the left margin, but not inside the binding offset:

```
\begin{textblock}{1}(0,6)\rule[0em]{2pt}{2pt}\hfill\end{textblock}}
\begin{textblock}{1}(0,7)\rule[0em]{2pt}{2pt}\hfill\end{textblock}}
```

Is it possible to move this mark to flush with the inner edge of the page, or a simpler way of achieving the same goal?
[image]

Comment: `\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(1cm,-10cm){\rule{2pt}{2pt}}
\put(1cm,-20cm){\rule{2pt}{2pt}}}`  Adapt the values to your need, the reference point for the put commands is the top left of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ulrike, that works well!  I defined a command to print the binding marks ...

```
\newcommand\showbindingmarks[1]{%
\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{%
    \put(#1,-0.11\paperheight){\rule{1pt}{1pt}}%
    \put(#1,-0.22\paperheight){\rule{1pt}{1pt}}%
    \put(#1,-0.33\paperheight){\rule{1pt}{1pt}}%
    \put(#1,-0.44\paperheight){\rule{1pt}{1pt}}%
    \put(#1,-0.55\paperheight){\rule{1pt}{1pt}}%
    \put(#1,-0.66\paperheight){\rule{1pt}{1pt}}%
    \put(#1,-0.77\paperheight){\rule{1pt}{1pt}}%
    \put(#1,-0.88\paperheight){\rule{1pt}{1pt}}%
}}
\newcommand\oddbindingmarks{\showbindingmarks{0pt}}
\newcommand\evenbindingmarks{\showbindingmarks{\paperwidth-1pt}}
```

And then I put it in the fancyhdr configuration:

```
\fancyhead[OR]{\oddbindingmarks}% Top right header
\fancyhead[EL]{\evenbindingmarks}% Top left header
```

[image]